# How to find a location is inside a country?

Tags: latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding, node-js

Given a Country Code and a Lat Lng pair, I want to find whether it is inside that country or not? What is the way to do it? Is there an algorithmic way to do this? I can accept certain amount of error.

I am node.js to implement this. Currently I do API call for Google to find the Country of the point. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse But that doesn't full fill my performance requirement.

Comment: What software are you using? There are a number of ways but much depends on the tools you have available.

Comment: @andunslg This question does not meet the site requirements. Please provide more detail. i.e. software, programming capability, api experience, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I have edit the question!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Node.js, you can use the [Node.js module](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal) for [GDAL](http://gdal.org/).  Get country outlines (e.g. GSHHS data set from [here](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html)).  Then simply script a point in a polygon algorithm using GDAL (several approaches are possible but a simple one is to test for an intersect between your point and the appropriate country polygon).